# WPF ListView with column names?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have this ListView and I'm using a DataTemplate (as you can see) for items.
How can i add column names to the ListView with this ItemTemplate definition?
I cannot use that `GridViewColumn` definition, because this ListView uses lazy data loading, so when there are too many rows, it fetches them on demand. `GridViewColumn` somehow does not function with this lazy loading.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="3">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="Transparent" MinWidth="580" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Benutzer.Value.Code}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Nachname}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="GeburtDate" StringFormat="{}{0:d}"/>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource StyleEditButton}" Content="Öffnen..." Tag="{Binding}"  Click="OpenPersonButton_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any point in using a `ListView` if, as you say, you cannot use `GridView` (or any other view).  I would exchange `ListView` for `ItemsControl` (or `ListBox` if you need a selectable item or any of the other things that `ListBox` offers).

If what you say is true, you could just use a stack panel to position a header row above your data rows:

```
<StackPanel>
  <!-- Header -->
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Width="220" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Code" />
    <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Nachname" />
    <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Vorname" />
    <TextBlock Width="70"  TextAlignment="Center" Text="GeburtDate" />
  </StackPanel>
  <!-- Data rows -->
  <ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="580">
            <TextBlock Width="220" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Benutzer.Value.Code}" />
            <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Nachname}" />
            <TextBlock Width="100" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}" />
            <TextBlock Width="70"  TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=GeburtDate, StringFormat={0:d}}" />
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource StyleEditButton}" Content="Öffnen..." Tag="{Binding}"  Click="OpenPersonButton_Click"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope that helps.  You might also like to read about virtualizing panels.  That might provide the kind of laziness you're talking about.